# save the cropped bounding box

Tags: python, crop, face-detection

I want to crop and save images from all the dataset which contains multi classes. but there is no output. and thank you.

```
def detect_face(img):
    detector = MTCNN()
    faces = detector.detect_faces(image) 
return faces     
                                                                               
dataset = '/content/drive/MyDrive/data_LFW/'

for img in glob.glob(dataset+'/*.*'):
    var_img = cv2.imread(img)
    face = detect_face(var_img)

    if (len(face) == 0):
       continue

    for(ex, ey, ew, eh) in face:
        crop_image = var_img[ey:ey+eh, ex:ex+ew]
                                                                                                           
     
   cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("/content/drive/MyDrive/data_crop",str(img)) ,crop_image)
```

Comment: maybe there is no input images therefore no output, or the detect_faces did not detect any face in input images. To check the hypothesis, just add a counter in the loop after continue to see how many faces detection are success. By the way, I spot an indentation error at "continue", shouldn't align with if statement, right?

Comment: my dataset contains two folders ,and each folder have other folders. It's still not working.

Comment: I see, then you might need to change the glob.glob statement to recursively traverse the two folders under  your dataset, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything else are correct (since I don't have your dataset and detector code), you may want to try to correct couple indentations to see if you can get some different results:

```
if (len(face) == 0):
    continue #correct the indentation and try again
```

and if you want to save every detection, correct the cv2.imwrite indentation as well. Since you have two sub folders under the dataset, then you need to change glob statement as shown below to visit all sub folders:

```
for img in glob.glob(dataset+'**/*.*'):
    var_img = cv2.imread(img)
    face = detect_face(var_img)

    if (len(face) == 0):
        continue

    for(ex, ey, ew, eh) in face:
        crop_image = var_img[ey:ey+eh, ex:ex+ew]
      
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("/content/drive/MyDrive/data_crop",str(img)),crop_image)
```